# Filter on value of variable in DataWeave only when variable has value otherwise ignore filter

Tags: mule, mule-studio, dataweave

In my application some queryparams are optional.
I'm storing these queryparams in variables.

I want to use those variables to filter on objects with DataWeave.
If no queryparam is passed in and variable is null or not there it needs to return all the objects, so no filtering.

Let's take the example of an energytype param that is passed in.
Stored in flow variable: energytypeVar (values could be something like "gas", "electricity", "water")

filter applied on object on the bottom:
filter $.attributes.energyType == flowVars.energytypeVar

I tried various ways with conditional logic when/otherwise to only filter when an actual value is provided.
Otherwise i don't want the filter to be executed at all, so all the objects are returned. 
At the moment when the variable had no valid 'energyType' the complete data object is empty.

### DW script

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/json
%var resourceUrl="https://hostname/devices"
%var collectionSize = sizeOf payload.Envelope.Body.GetEnergyDevicesResponse.GetEnergyDevicesResult
---
{
meta:{code: 200, timestamp: now},

data: payload.Envelope.Body.GetEnergyDevicesResponse.GetEnergyDevicesResult map {

        type: "device",
        id: $.EnergyDeviceId,
        attributes: {
        energyType: $.EnergyType,
        deviceModel: $.HWModel,
        serialNumber: $.SerialNumber,
        name: $.Name,

        applianceType: $.applianceType,
        isCentralMeter: $.IsCentralMeter as :boolean,
        isSwitchable: $.IsSwitchable as :boolean,
        isOnline: $.IsOnline as :boolean,
        isProducer: $.IsProducer as :boolean,
        isSwitchedOn: $.IsSwitchedOn as :boolean,
        isLiveUsageEnabled: $.IsLiveUsageEnabled as :boolean,
        index: {
                value: $.MeterIndexValue,
                unit: 'm3' unless $.EnergyType == "electricity" otherwise "Wh",
                timestamp: $.MeterIndexTimestamp
                } when ($.IsCentralMeter == "true") otherwise null  

    },
    links: {
        self: resourceUrl ++ '/' ++ $.EnergyDeviceId
    }

} filter $.attributes.energyType == flowVars.energytypeVar
}
```

**Solution after answer**
(Applied extra filtering)

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/json
%var resourceUrl="https://hostname/devices"
%var collectionSize = sizeOf payload.Envelope.Body.GetEnergyDevicesResponse.GetEnergyDevicesResult
---
using (result = payload.Envelope.Body.GetEnergyDevicesResponse.GetEnergyDevicesResult map {

        type: "device",
        id: $.EnergyDeviceId,
        attributes: {
        energyType: $.EnergyType,
        deviceModel: $.HWModel,
        serialNumber: $.SerialNumber,
        name: $.Name,

        applianceType: $.applianceType,
        isCentralMeter: $.IsCentralMeter as :boolean,
        isSwitchable: $.IsSwitchable as :boolean,
        isOnline: $.IsOnline as :boolean,
        isProducer: $.IsProducer as :boolean,
        isSwitchedOn: $.IsSwitchedOn as :boolean,
        isLiveUsageEnabled: $.IsLiveUsageEnabled as :boolean,
        index: {
                value: $.MeterIndexValue,
                unit: 'm3' unless $.EnergyType == "electricity" otherwise "Wh",
                timestamp: $.MeterIndexTimestamp
                } when ($.IsCentralMeter == "true") otherwise null  

    },
    links: {
        self: resourceUrl ++ '/' ++ $.EnergyDeviceId
    }

})

{
meta:{code: 200, timestamp: now},

data: result filter ($.id == flowVars.deviceId) when (flowVars.deviceId != 0) otherwise {
data: result filter ($.attributes.energyType == flowVars.energyType) when flowVars.energyType != 0
otherwise result 
} distinctBy $.data
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this.

```
            %dw 1.0
        %output application/json
        %var resourceUrl="https://hostname/devices"
        %var collectionSize = sizeOf payload.Envelope.Body.GetEnergyDevicesResponse.GetEnergyDevicesResult
        ---
        {
        meta:{code: 200, timestamp: now},
        data: (payload.Envelope.Body.GetEnergyDevicesResponse.GetEnergyDevicesResult map {

                type: "device",
                id: $.EnergyDeviceId,
                attributes: {
                energyType: $.EnergyType,
                deviceModel: $.HWModel,
                serialNumber: $.SerialNumber,
                name: $.Name,

                applianceType: $.applianceType,
                isCentralMeter: $.IsCentralMeter as :boolean,
                isSwitchable: $.IsSwitchable as :boolean,
                isOnline: $.IsOnline as :boolean,
                isProducer: $.IsProducer as :boolean,
                isSwitchedOn: $.IsSwitchedOn as :boolean,
                isLiveUsageEnabled: $.IsLiveUsageEnabled as :boolean,
                index: {
                        value: $.MeterIndexValue,
                        unit: 'm3' unless $.EnergyType == "electricity" otherwise "Wh",
                        timestamp: $.MeterIndexTimestamp
                        } when ($.IsCentralMeter == "true") otherwise null  

            },
            links: {
                self: resourceUrl ++ '/' ++ $.EnergyDeviceId
            }

        } filter $.attributes.energyType == flowVars.energytypeVar) when flowVars.energytypeVar? otherwise (payload.Envelope.Body.GetEnergyDevicesResponse.GetEnergyDevicesResult map {

                type: "device",
                id: $.EnergyDeviceId,
                attributes: {
                energyType: $.EnergyType,
                deviceModel: $.HWModel,
                serialNumber: $.SerialNumber,
                name: $.Name,

                applianceType: $.applianceType,
                isCentralMeter: $.IsCentralMeter as :boolean,
                isSwitchable: $.IsSwitchable as :boolean,
                isOnline: $.IsOnline as :boolean,
                isProducer: $.IsProducer as :boolean,
                isSwitchedOn: $.IsSwitchedOn as :boolean,
                isLiveUsageEnabled: $.IsLiveUsageEnabled as :boolean,
                index: {
                        value: $.MeterIndexValue,
                        unit: 'm3' unless $.EnergyType == "electricity" otherwise "Wh",
                        timestamp: $.MeterIndexTimestamp
                        } when ($.IsCentralMeter == "true") otherwise null  

            },
            links: {
                self: resourceUrl ++ '/' ++ $.EnergyDeviceId
            }

        })
        }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! This almost worked, i've changed the filter query to: '} filter $.attributes.energyType == flowVars.energyTypeVar ) when flowVars.energyTypeVar != "" otherwise (payload.Envelope.Body.GetEnergyDevicesResponse.GetEnergyDevicesResult map { etcetc...     I thought about this solution but it's quite strange, should be an easier way i think. If i change something in my code, i need to change it at both transformations, using a variable of function for example.

Comment: You can use using keyword for your fields logic and  operate on this variable with conditional logic. So you don't need to change code at two place.